# Using @Autowired to set Class in Generics

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to setup a generic DAO and service for a project i'm working at, it all seems to be working except I have to manually set the `class<T> clazz` everywhere I instantiate a repository, which is ok for the ones I have an entire class for (such as the `clientRepository` one below).

I tried to do the `@Autowired setClazz(Class<T> clazz)` in the AbstractRepository to solve it but it just doesn't work, when I debug `findById(Long id)`, the clazz is null.

Is there any way to do this or do I really have to call the setClazz everywhere?

AbstractRepository

```java
public abstract class AbstractRepository<T extends IGenericEntity> {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "clima_PU")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private Session session;

    private Class<T> clazz;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public void setClazz(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public T findByID(Long id) {
        return (T) entityManager.find(clazz, id);
    }
}
```

GenericRepository

```java
@Repository
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class GenericRepository<T extends AbstractEntity> extends AbstractRepository<T> implements IGenericRepository<T> {

}
```

ClientRepository

```java
public class ClientRepository extends GenericRepository<ClientEntity> {
    /* Custom Queries for Clients */
}
```

Comment: so there is nothing to do with `spring-data-jpa` as you want to rollout your own repository ? seems like you want re-invent the things that `spring-data-jpa` is current doing by yourself?

Comment: @KenChan I'm building on top of what's already there, maybe I'm doing stuff wrong, but there's some queries already made in some of the repositories and I'm not ready to redo all that work too...

What's the correct way of doing this?